# XAML reader duplicate print

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My code calling this method after click on button. This method should print in MessageBox keys with values on lines.

```
public static void LoadFromFile()
{
    try
    {
        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(@"config.xml"))
        {
            string sourceValue = "";
            string sourceKey = "";
            string element = "";
            string messageBox = "";

            while (xr.Read())
            {
                if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    element = xr.Name;
                    if (element == "source")
                    {
                        sourceKey = xr.GetAttribute("key");
                    }
                }
                else if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                {
                    if (element == "value")
                    {
                        sourceValue = xr.Value;
                    }
                }
                else if ((xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement) && (xr.Name == "source"))
                {
                    // there is problem
                    messageBox += sourceKey + " " + sourceValue + "\n";
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(messageBox);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
    }
}
```

Method prints every keys with value exactly what I want. **But** last key with value method print twice. In source config.xml is only 3 keys and 3 values, but method prints 4 keys and 4 values.

This is example of output:

> key1 myValue1
>
> key2 myValue2
>
> **key3 myValue3**
>
> **key3 myValue3**

And another example:

> dog Woof
>
> cat Meow
>
> **duck Quack**
>
> **duck Quack**

This is my XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<source>
  <source key="key1">
    <value>myValue1</value>
  </source>
  <source key="key2">
    <value>myValue2</value>
  </source>
  <source key="key3">
    <value>myValue3</value>
  </source>
</source>
```

Comment: @EliArbel My question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer element is also called "source"

So, at the end there are 2 "source" end elements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the closing element of the root `source` causes you to print the value twice. You can fix this by either selecting a different name for the root element or by changing the method like so:

```
while (xr.Read())
{
    if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        element = xr.Name;
        if (element == "source")
        {
            sourceKey = xr.GetAttribute("key");
        }
    }
    else if (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
    {
        if (element == "value")
        {
            sourceValue = xr.Value;
        }
    }
    else if (sourceValue != "" && (xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement) && (xr.Name == "source"))
    {
        // there is problem
        messageBox += sourceKey + " " + sourceValue + "\n";
        sourceValue = "";
    }
}
```